# Is it possible to delay the execution of a script without blocking other scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

if I don't have control about the JavaScript file order, is it somehow possible to delay the execution of my script, but let in this time other scripts execute.
For example my script A is loaded before script B and C. But script B & C are loading some data to the DOM that I need to work with. Can I somehow delay my script, so that script B & C can run and load the data?
Can I e.g. set a 5 sec delay to the execution of my script, let the other scripts execute in this 5 sec and then execute my script?
Or is the only solution to add my script as last one?

Thank you

Comment: Load script D that controls the loading and execution order of A,B, and C

Comment: You could use `setInterval()` to wait some arbitrary period before executing the code, but what's wrong with loading your scripts in the appropriate order?

Comment: You can add the `async` or `defer` attributes to the first script.

Comment: If B and C are loading data asynchronously, you should reconsider your entire approach. Delaying the script by a fixed amount of seconds is bound to either annoy the user or fail miserably. The proper solution is to use Promises or async await (or oldschool callbacks) to 1. load all the data 2. update the DOM 3. run the code from script A

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular well for an university project I wanted to know if it is possible. Simply try and lern stuff. But I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean exactly? Can you please give an example?

Comment: `<script src="URL" defer>`